# TFS Check-in oddity causes file to become a different file entirely

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-2015, tfvc

I'm trying to figure out the root cause of a strange TFS error we are seeing in our current instance.  It wasn't noticed until after a server move, but I'm not sure if they're directly related, because the error seems to be showing up for check-ins about a week prior to the move, as well as all those following it.

We first noticed the problem when I tried to get latest, and got several errors indicating:
"The downloaded file is corrupt.  Please get the file again."

Upon looking into the error, we have noticed that starting as of a single check-in every code update has resulted in files being replaced with the contents of other files, ranging from project files to binary executable files (presumably assembly DLLs), rather than the expected content which is still present on our local development machines.

I don't have admin access to the servers myself, but am looking for ideas on possible causes and/or fixes for our team to investigate.

Comment: Does the problem appear after updating TFS?

Comment: What patch level of TFS 2015? It's going to be really difficult for you to get help for an ~8 year old version of TFS that's been out of support for ages.

Comment: The 'About' screen says: "Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
Version 14.0.23128.0".  I'm fully aware that I'm going for a 'hail mary' here.  We were still maintaining code in VS 2008 (including a .NET 2.0 app) until the middle of the year when we got the solutions migrated to VS 2012, with new projects being developed in VS 2022.

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT, I'm not quite sure what that question means.  If I recall correctly, we were on TFS 2013 prior to the server move.  (We got bought, and as part of the transition, we had to move everything to the new parent company's servers.)  I have no access to the old server at this point, but the first check-in that displays the issue on the new server is a check-in that was done on the old server.  An earlier check-in on the *same* day (less than two minutes prior) is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of searching, I finally found another mention of this sort of thing happening, along with a solution that appears to have worked.

Clear the Application Tier cache.

[MSDN Archived Forums: TFS swapping contents of files](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e9849fa4-494d-4c19-9ca8-6234ce973dd1/tfs-swapping-contents-of-files?forum=tfsadmin)